# primefaces p: media does not update the contents of the PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using a p: primefaces media to display a pdf in a dialog generated with iText but after the first time it no longer updates the contents of the document

To show it I have to completely update the page already, which does not work if I do an update from the page.

This way I show the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnPreview" value="#{msg['view.preview']}"
                    actionListener="#{circularRequestBean.generarPdf()}"
                    class="button button-text" 
            oncomplete="PF('dialog')    .show()" update="tabView:popupAlertMessage,:tabView:frmEditCircular:panelBody" />
```

This is the dialog

```
<p:dialog header="#{msg['view.preview']}" widgetVar="popupView" modal="true"
    id="pdfViewer" responsive="true" width="70%">

    <p:media id="viwer" value="#{circularRequestBean.previewCircular}" player="pdf"  widgetVar="mediaPDf"
         height="600">
            <f:param  name="idPdf" value="#{circularRequestBean.idFile}" />
         </p:media>
</p:dialog>
```

in the bean

```
public StreamedContent getPreviewCircular() {
    return previewCircular;
}
```

How can I update the content of the p: media?